# Prevent output escaping in Twig function extension

Tags: symfony, twig

I have created a Twig extension:

```
{{ image ("image.png", 200) }}
```

HI know I can just do

```
{{ image ("image.png", 200)|raw }}
```

...but I would prefer to use PHP code so that everything (from this 'image' extension) is not escaped.

I can't see this possible.

I know I can prevent all output escaping in Twig, but I just want this one extension not to escape output, and everything else to do so.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This can be done by adding [an option](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping) at the extension registration.

```php
public function getFilters(){
    return array(
        // ...
        'image' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'imageFilter',
            array('is_safe' => array('html'))
        ),
        // ...
    );
}
```

This will provide unescaped input HTML and return unescaped HTML output. If you need to work with escaped HTML input, see the option `'pre_escaped' => 'html'`.

Comment: NOTE! You can only use `pre_escape` for filters, and the OP is specifically using a function, where [pre_escape has no effect](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions). You need to [manually escape function inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097270).

Answer (score 15):

For twig function extension do this

```
public function getFunctions()
{
  return array(
     new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
        'image', 
        array($this, 'image'), 
        array('is_safe' => array('html')))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use a function

```php
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('html', function ($code) {
   return new \Twig_Markup($code, "utf-8");
}));
```

```twig
{{ html(myhtmlcode) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

In twig version 2 you can solve it like this:

**environment**:
    Symfony 4 and twig-bundle ^4.0

**code**:

```
public function getFilters(): array
{
    return [,
        new TwigFilter('image', [$this, 'image'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
    ];
}
```