# Twig: How can I manually escape inside a custom function?

Tags: symfony, twig

I wrote my own Twig function that outputs HTML, so I have `is_safe` set to `html` so that Twig knows not to escape the output my function.

However, my function takes arguments. One of the arguments is placed in the output directly. I want to escape this before outputting it. So it seems I just need to be able to manually escape the option value before outputting it.

I can't find how to do this. Anyone know?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to store the twig enviroment which in turn is passed to twig_escape_filter

```
class TournExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $env;

    public function initRuntime(\Twig_Environment $env)
    {
        parent::initRuntime($env);
        $this->env = $env;
    }
    protected function escape($string)
    {
        return twig_escape_filter($this->env,$string);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. I expected [pre_escape](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping) to also escape input arguments, but after [a simple test](http://pastebin.com/hzz023dF), no, it only escapes filter's input. Good to know.

Comment: It is briefly mentioned in the twig dogs that twig functions don't support `pre_escape`. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: I probably should point out that I no longer use the posted escape function.  I find that generating html inside of twig extensions tend to make my code more difficult to maintain.  Consider using templates to generate the html.