# twig extension - php equivalent of twig's include

Tags: php, symfony, twig, extension-methods

I have a library of widgets (js and other files) which instead of writing

```
{% include 'path' %}
```

all the time I have written an extension to just include them with a function call like so:

```
{% widget('name') %}
```

So my question is how do I re implement the twig include function?
Is it just a matter of returning a php include or is it a file_get_contents?

Examples:

```
<?php

    class Extensions 
    {
        public function widget($name) 
        {
             return include 'filepath/' . $name . '.html.twig';
             // or 
             return file_get_content('filepath/' . $name . '.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Updated: 
I'm using file_get_contents and I get the following returned:

```
alert('FROM HERE');
// AS
alert(&#039;FROM HERE&#039;);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730037/prevent-output-escaping-in-twig-function-extension twig escape the output from the extension  you need to disable this

Comment: Your awesome. Thank you

Comment: Twig as already an include function , why do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its some more they parse the templates on call

look:

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L1287

edit: `file_get_contents` do the job. `include` makes more than only output the content

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I'm not quire needing it that in depth though. 
I just simply need to retrieve the html from that file. 
Do you think file_get_contents is a good idea or could that get too heavy?

Comment: `file_get_contents` do the job. `include` makes more than only output the content

Comment: Great. Thank you. I just have one more question. Im getting the file contents but it gets echoed at encoded chars. Would you know a way around this? Thanks

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: @TheMan68 Mark your function as [safe](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#automatic-escaping)